# How to get an Id Perspective of Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

It is possible to launch eclipse with -perspective idPerspective

so how can I get this idPerspective ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are running Eclipse with PDE (Plugin Development Environment), hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to use the **Plugin Menu Spy**. The cursor will change its' shape, now press the desired perspective button and you will get the perspective ID.

Another option is to run a plug-in search (from Search → Plugin). Look for the string "`org.eclipse.ui.perspectives`" which is the name of the extension point that defines a perspective.

If you don't have PDE, you can search for the same string in the plugin.xml files which are found inside the plugins JARs. If you have a tool that can search within JARs, that would be helpful. Otherwise, you will need to guess which JAR to open for the search (or open all the JARs).

Answer (score 3):

Without PDE and without searching JAR files, you can also look inside your workspace metadata folder for the workbench configuration file. In my setup, the path is **{workspace}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xml**. Simply search the contents of this file for the key phrase **persp.perspSC**. You will see some lines such as:

```
<tags>persp.perspSC:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaPerspective</tags>
<tags>persp.perspSC:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaBrowsingPerspective</tags>
```

Where the text after the colon is the perspective ID.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The Plugin Menu Spy (although working in principle) didn't work for the perspective symbol buttons (at least in my case, with the Eclipse BIRT Report Designer)

Answer (score 1):

place this script in your eclipse plugin dir and run it

```
#!/bin/sh

for jar in $(find . -name '*.jar')
do
    plugin=$(zipinfo -l "$jar" plugin.xml 2> /dev/null)
    if [ "$plugin" = "" ]
    then
        continue
    fi

    preferences=$(unzip -q -c "$jar" 'plugin.xml' | xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//perspective/@id')
    if [ "$preferences" != "" ]
    then
        echo "$preferences\n"
    fi
done
```

Comment: This requires extra software and only works in unix-like operating systems.

Comment: Nice!  Also, thanks for turning me onto xmlstarlet..!  Wish I'd discovered it years ago.